# Calculate string from field in temporary table select using sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a temporary table which I can select out of as follows:

```
select 
    testId
    ,testoutput
from 
    #testResults
```

This yields results such as the following:

```
ID Result
1   4303
2   -150000*200*3= -90000000
3   4.2016
4   3205000
```

The second value is due to some of our tests outputting the calculation rather than value for readability in later reports.

I'd like to turn that calculation back into a number, which I believe is doable via sp_executesql...

I've changed my select to:

```
select 
    testId
    ,case
        WHEN isnumeric(trim(testoutput)) = 1 THEN pr.expectedOutput
        WHEN CHARINDEX('=', testoutput) != 0 then 
            exec sp_executesql N'rtrim(left(testoutput, CHARINDEX(''='', testoutput) - 1))'
    END                                                                         
from 
    #testOuput
```

i.e. when there's an "=" sign, then split off what's the left of the sign and try to exec sp_executesql on it.

This throws all sorts of syntax errors, which I can't get my head around.

I'd really appreciate any help with the syntax of the sp_executesql

Comment: You can't execute a stored procedure inside a statement, or access outside columns in dynamic SQL. This would require icky, icky looping with a cursor (or generating one gargantuan dynamic statement covering all rows, which isn't much better). Not to mention the havoc caused if some joker decides to set `Result` to `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT`, of course (or some variation thereof that will work with your code). Consider solving this problem properly, by having actual client code with an actual parser to parse what you're actually outputting and nothing more than that.

Comment: "You can't execute a stored procedure inside a statement" - that was definitely my first problem! I'll abort this aprroach - thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also extract the result of the calculation:

**SQL Server without `TRIM` or `TRY_PARSE`**

```
SELECT testId, CASE
  WHEN ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(testoutput))) = 1 THEN pr.expectedOutput
  WHEN CHARINDEX('=', testoutput) > 0 THEN
    LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(testoutput, CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(testoutput))-1)))
END                                                                         
FROM #testOuput
```

**SQL Server with [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) and [`TRY_PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql)**

```
SELECT testId, CASE
  WHEN TRY_PARSE(TRIM(testoutput) AS NUMERIC) IS NOT NULL THEN pr.expectedOutput
  WHEN CHARINDEX('=', testoutput) > 0 THEN
    TRIM(RIGHT(testoutput, CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(testoutput))-1))
END                                                                         
FROM #testOuput
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8374231c9f44ffaeb29492517d24fadb)

Comment: I just stared at this in total disbelief like I was an idiot for not noticing that. omg - thanks very much!

Comment: Any particular reason to eschew [`trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/). Using [`try_parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would be more reliable.